# Do LastOrDefault() and Last() methods iterate each and every element of the list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, enumeration

Do LastOrDefault() and Last() methods **iterate** each and every element of the list to find the last element? or Are they returning the value by searching based on the **index** of the element?

Comment: It *might*, but only if the collection does not implement IList.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,75722fd194dc2e0e

Comment: You do unfortunately need to check these against the source for each operator. LINQ gets most of the `IList<T>`/`ICollection<T>` optimizations, but it misses some important ones, such as [`SequenceEqual`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,920).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a type `IList` then no, it won't iterate each and every element as that would be very inefficient.

This is what they do:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null) {
            int count = list.Count;
            if (count > 0) return list[count - 1];
        }
        else {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
                if (e.MoveNext()) {
                    TSource result;
                    do {
                        result = e.Current;
                    } while (e.MoveNext());
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        throw Error.NoElements();
    }
```

and `LastOrDefault`:

```
public static TSource LastOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
            if (list != null) {
                int count = list.Count;
                if (count > 0) return list[count - 1];
            }
            else {
                using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
                    if (e.MoveNext()) {
                        TSource result;
                        do {
                            result = e.Current;
                        } while (e.MoveNext());
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            return default(TSource);
}
```

Note, as there are couple overloads of each method I've only shown one of each above, but if you're interested in the others then [feel free to have a look at the source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs):